# python : how to plot a curve over a heatmap

Tags: python, plot, visualization, heatmap

I have those dataframes :

```
# DataFrame example
data_flexibilities = {
    'power': [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
    '2022-06-01T02:00:00+00:00': [1, 7, 9, 10, 5],
    '2022-06-01T03:00:00+00:00': [6, 7, 1, 4, 5],
    '2022-06-01T05:00:00+00:00': [8, 5, 3, 7, 8],
}
all_flexibilities = pd.DataFrame(data_flexibilities)
all_flexibilities.set_index('power', inplace=True)
all_flexibilities.columns = pd.to_datetime(all_flexibilities.columns)


data_curve = {
    'dates': ['2022-06-01T02:00:00+00:00', '2022-06-01T03:00:00+00:00', '2022-06-01T5:00:00+00:00'],
    'power_consumption': [0, 2, 2]
}
curve_to_plot = pd.DataFrame(data_curve)
curve_to_plot['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(curve_to_plot['dates'])
```

I want to get the heatmap from the first dataframe (the dates as x and the power as y) plus the curve from the second dataframe over it (power=f(dates)).

Because of my real data, the heatmap must be plotted with a log scale as in the example figure.

I didn't manage to find a way to do it properly.

I want the result to be a figure like this one :
[image: example figure]

thanks !!

Could you gave a direction do to it?

Comment: Could you show what plotting code do you have, and what is the problem with what you get. It is try hard to figure out what you are trying to plot exactly (your example figure obviously is not related to your example data, so it doesn't help to understand what must be plotted from your data). Plus, we don't even know what plotting library you are using.

Comment: If it is `matplotlib`, I would say that what you are missing is probably the `extent` option of imshow, that allows to set the scale of an image (which by default is just in pixels), and therefore to choose how that image would fit under another curve. Also, maybe some `plt.yscale('log')` if you want the scale to be logarithmic